# Linking bookmarklet with site's bookmark

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser, bookmarklet, bookmarks

I made working bookmarklet to alter some stuff on some site. What I would like to do, is to link somehow this bookmarklet with that site/bookmark containing url address of that site. I was trying to achieve that by using **window.location** and redirect to that page at the beggining of my bookmarklet code, but I found out, that it's not possible. **Is there some other way to make it work just like that, with one click, be able to go to certain page and alter some stuff ??**

PS. I'm using Firefox.

Comment: No. you can use greasemonkey or similar to always execute a script on a specific URL

Comment: @mplungjan Fair enough, but I don't see how come my question is a duplicate of a question that you provided, lol.

Comment: _link somehow this bookmarklet with that site/bookmark containing url address of that site._ sounds EXACTLY like the title of the duplicate. To get the question reopened you just have to provide enough detail to show otherwise